# search a dataset for an input variable as a string

Tags: r

I have a function that takes an input which is a word. The function is supposed to find how many times that word appears in a dataset. However, I'm having trouble getting my function to search for the word and not my input variable (x). The code is below.

```
numObserv <- function(x){

  nrow(x<-iris[iris$species=="x",])

}
```

I would want it so that if I type numObserv(specificword) it would work. I think my error has to do with the "x" part.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put `x` in quotes because it looks for literal "x" in the data which is not present.

```
numObserv <- function(df, x) {
      sum(df$Species == x)
      #Or same using nrow as in your attempt
      #nrow(df[df$Species == x, ])
}
numObserv(iris, "setosa")
#[1] 50
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize I could type into the function("word")